# String.Format(format, dateTime) method returns short date with dot appended at the end

Tags: c#, datetime

I am formatting a dateTime with the following line of code:

```
String.Format ("{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}", dateTime);
```

The string I get back looks like: `Tue., Jul. 11, 2017` rather than `Tue, Jul 11, 2017`.
I don't need those dots appended at the end of short day and month. According to the C# docs, output string doesn't have dots in it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your code doesn't produce the same results for me. I get: `Thu, Jul 13, 2017` when I execute: `Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}");`

Comment: $ operator seems doesn't have format function? @RufusL

Comment: @LeiYang the `$` is used to allow inline formatting, or [String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings). It's a "new" feature in C# 6.0. The code above is the same as: `Console.WriteLine($"{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}", DateTime.Now);`

Comment: @LeiYang it has. $ is simple shortcut for String.Format

Comment: but can it be used that way, i don't think it will work

Comment: It allows you to specify the objects inside the string, like `$"{someObject}"` instead of after the string, like `string.Format("{0}", someObject)`

Comment: i never know $ allow a format string after **,**, maybe it's my fault, i'll check later

Comment: @LeiYang It's not particularly the `$` at work here, it's the style of `{object:format}` passed to `String.Format()` or `$`. Note the colon after `DateTime.Now` in their example

Comment: @LeiYang check generated IL code. $ is a syntax sugar from C# compiler. E.g. `$"hello {x}"` will be compiled to `String.Format("hello {0}", x)`

Comment: @RufusL i just tested your code **the same as**, it simply outputs the format string `ddd, MMM d, yyyy`, instead of time. can you have a test?

Comment: @Rob now i know that, `Console.WriteLine` calls `string.Format`. but rufusl has a wrong statement in his comments, i tested it.

Comment: @RufusL i mean `Console.WriteLine($"{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}", DateTime.Now);`

Comment: @LeiYang Oh, I see. Yes, that one should not have the `$`. I meant to be contrasting the "old way" with using string interpolation. That one I did not test. Just remove the `$` if you're going to use a comma-separated argument list

Comment: ok, i also learned $ allows a : to separate format string.

Comment: @LeiYang Well, that's also supported without the `$`, like: `Console.WriteLine("{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}", DateTime.Now);`

Comment: i knew that. all these actually calls string.Format.

Comment: I'm curious, what is your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture) and .NET Framework version by the way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a locale issue. To use an invariant locale, use:

```
String.Format (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}", dateTime);
```